# Add rows from 4 different tables

Tags: php, sql

Is there any query where i can retrieve the rows of table which are related to same id in all tables.

If the user enters fromzip code as 64083 and to as 94568 in html form i need a sql query to fetch the  nextday, scndday and thirdday rows which are related to that zipcodes to be displayed in webpage, in this case the id's with same number must be displayed from all tables of the database.

table1

```
idzipform    fromzip    tozip
    1         64083     94568
    2         94568     64083
```

table2

```
idnextday    fedex     usps    ups     day
    1        50.29     90.80   60.60   Nextday
    2        90.99     80.88   70.70   Nextday
```

table3

```
idscndday    fedex     usps    ups     day
    1        20.29    19.80   16.60   Scndday
    2        19.99    18.88   17.70   Scndday
```

table4

```
idthirdday    fedex     usps    ups     day
    1         9.29      9.80    6.60   Thirdday
    2         9.99      8.88    7.70   Thirdday
```

Output should be like this

```
                   fromzip        tozip
                    64083         94568

   day       fedex     usps      ups

 Nextday     50.29     90.80     60.60
 Scndday     20.29     19.80     16.60
Thirdday     9.29      9.80       6.60
```

Output must be 1st rows in all tables which have same id.

Is this possible, please help if it don't should i add any foreign keys or primary keys.

Comment: What does your question have to do with php? Are you wanting to format the output with php (so the output you get from sql is unimportant)? Which rdbms are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @TZHX - I assume the "tables" are mysql tables and not html tables

Comment: @mplungjan that's nice? I assume the same thing.

Comment: I just react to _What does your question have to do with php_

Comment: This smacks of poor design. You do not need three separate tables for different delivery speeds

Comment: Please don't spam tag. I removed most of the tags and you need to use the tag related to the RDBMS used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with UNION statement

```
SELECT f.day, f.fedex, f.usps, f.ups
FROM table2 f
INNER JOIN table1 z ON z.idzipform = f.idnextday
WHERE z.fromzip = '64083' AND z.tozip = '94568'
UNION 
SELECT s.day, s.fedex, s.usps, s.ups
FROM table3 s
INNER JOIN table1 z ON z.idzipform = s.idscndday
WHERE z.fromzip = '64083' AND z.tozip = '94568'
UNION 
SELECT t.day, t.fedex, t.usps, t.ups
FROM table4 t
INNER JOIN table1 z ON z.idzipform = t.idthirdday
WHERE z.fromzip = '64083' AND z.tozip = '94568'
```